# How to embed angular website into flutter?

Tags: angular, flutter

I want to embed my angular website in flutter website. I searched a lot but didn't find any meaningful solution. Can someone help me on this?

I want to know,

1. Is it possible to embed my angular website into flutter website?
2. I am also managing the user session with firebase token so, Is it possible to manage auth token?

Comment: You'll probably need to give a lot more info, have you tried iframes :D?